# Issue with the after function of the Date object in java 8

Tags: java, date

I have a problem with the after() function in the date object.
This is the function I'm trying to run:

```
    private void setDebitDateInAction(Action action) {

    // The day the credit card debit is made
    int dD = action.getMethodPayment().getDebitDate();
    System.out.println("1) The debit day is every "+dD+" in  month.");

    //The date the purchase was made
    Date actionDate = action.getActionDate();
    System.out.println( "2) The purchase was in "+ actionDate.toString() );

    //The date the purchase will be charged
    Date debitDate = actionDate;
    System.out.println("3) Currently the debit date is "+debitDate.toString()  ); 

    //0 means immediate charge
    if(dD == 0) {
        //Leave the billing date as the purchase date.
    }else {
        // Change the day of the billing date
        debitDate.setDate(dD);
        System.out.println("4) The day of the debit date has changed to "+dD+" and new the debit date is " +debitDate.toString()  ); 
        if(actionDate.after(debitDate)) {
            debitDate.setMonth(debitDate.getMonth()+1);
            System.out.println("5) The month of the debit date has changed to "+debitDate.getMonth() + 1 +" and new the debit date is " +debitDate.toString()  ); 
        }
    }
    action.setDebitDate(debitDate);
    System.out.println("6) ActionDebit is set to" +debitDate.toString()  ); 
}
```

This is what I get in the console after I put in the Action function where the actionDate is 15/07/2019 and the dateDate of methodPayment (for credit purposes) is 10.

```
1) The debit day is every 10 in  month.
2) The purchase was in Mon Jul 15 03:00:00 IDT 2019
3) Currently the debit date is Mon Jul 15 03:00:00 IDT 2019
4) The day of the debit date has changed to 10 and now the debit date is Wed Jul 10 03:00:00 IDT 2019
6) ActionDebit is set toWed Jul 10 03:00:00 IDT 2019
```

I expect the billing date to be wished for 10/08/2019 but not successful.
For some reason he fails to recognize that the purchase date is after the billing date.

Comment: Don't use `Date`, especially not in Java 8 (or later). `Date` is poorly designed. `Date` is long outdated. You probably want `LocalDate`, though based on your exact requirements it may be some other class from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. And even if you insist on `Date`, stay far away from its `setMonth` method. It's been deprecated for over 20 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two (following) scenarios-

1. CompareTo() - In case you are using the correct `debitDate:

This is because your `actionDate` and `debitDate` are same, hence `if(actionDate.after(debitDate))` will always return false in case of both dates being equal.

You should be using `compareTo()` instead.

The code should look something like this:

```
if(actionDate.compareTo(debitDate) >=0) {
debitDate.setMonth(debitDate.getMonth()+1);
            System.out.println("5) The month of the debit date has changed to "+debitDate.getMonth() + 1 +" and new the debit date is " +debitDate.
}
```

2. You're using wrong `debitDate`:
   You should set the right debitDate, and the code should look like:

   //The date the purchase will be charged

   Date debitDate = action.getMethodPayment().getDebitDate();

I hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You set your Dates to the same value:

```
Date actionDate = action.getActionDate();
Date debitDate = actionDate;
```

when you now check

```
if(actionDate.after(debitDate))
```

you get "false" - because the dates are equal. You need to set the dates differently

you are calling a debitDate, but this seems to be not a correct date ... check this

```
action.getMethodPayment().getDebitDate()
```

Comment: I forgot to note that the debitDate object returned from the methodPayent object is an int type that specifies only the day the billing is made